# how to add scrollbar to a frame that is set to pack_propagate(False)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-canvas

i want to make a chatroom GUI where the user's messages will show up on the right side, and other users' messages will show up on the left side.

in order to do so without having the frame on the canvas shrink to the size of the labels, i have to put `frame.pack_propagate(False)`

however, doing so disables my scrollbar. from my understanding it is happening because the frame is now 'locked' and any widgets packed into it will simply 'overflow' out of the frame's view.

the mainly important code is as follows:

```py
# main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Chatroom")
root.config(bg="red")
root.geometry("1200x800")
root.resizable(False, False)


chat_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="gray30", height=600, width=1200)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=chat_canvas.yview)
chat_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar .set)

msg_frame = tk.Frame(chat_canvas, bg="blue", height=600, width=1200)
msg_frame.pack_propagate(False) #<-- this is a must for me as i want the messages to show up 
                                # on the right side of the frame. without it the frame will
                                # shrink to the size of the label and stick it to the left
                                # however without it the scrollbar works rather fine(?)

chat_canvas.pack(fill='both', side='left', expand=True)
scrollbar .pack(side='right', fill='y')

chat_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=msg_frame, anchor='nw')

msg_frame.bind('<Configure>', func=lambda ev: chat_canvas.configure(scrollregion=chat_canvas.bbox('all')))
```

when i want to print a message into the frame, the following function executes:

```
def print_message(msg):
    msg_label = tk.Label(msg_frame, text=msg, bg="gray30",state='disabled')
    msg_label.pack(anchor='ne', padx=10)
```

the GUI looks like this without any option to scroll (frame is blue, canvas has white borders):

[image]

what am i missing?

Comment: You can specify the width when calling `chat_canvas.create_window(..., width=1180)` and then you can remove the line `msg_frame.pack_propagate()`.  But better use `Text` widget for the chat window.

Comment: @acw1668 im trying to test the text widget with the scrollbar, and i managed to attach them to each other, however scrolling only works through the scrollwheel, or going up\down manually with the arrow keys, and not by dragging the slider.

Comment: @acw1668 also i still get the same problem where i want some text to show up on the left side and some on the right, and using labels positions the messages correctly, but now i cant scroll the labels

Comment: Instead of using labels, why not just write the text messages directly on the canvas? That gives you the ability to align messages on the right.

Comment: i somehow managed in the end to get what i want, but i did do some tests with text and ultimately felt like, despite it being probably the best approach, that it will limit my options further down the road.

either that or i am just too inexperienced hehe.
anyways thanks for the guidance and insight :P